# Is there an easy way to prove "2^(log n) Ω(n)"? - Big Omega question

Tags: math, big-o

Is there a way to prove 2^(log n) Ω(n)?
(This is log base of 2)

I thought I could choose a constant as 1/4 when n >= 4, but I can't seem to find a way to show n^(1/4) =< log n. Maybe there is an easier way?

Comment: Um, isn't `2^log(n)` exactly equal to `n`?  That's the very definition of a logarithm.  Maybe I don't understand the question.  I assume you are asking if the function `2^log(n)` **is in** the class `Ω(n)`; you seem to be missing a verb or a ∈ symbol between them.

Comment: You are right. I meant to say 2^log(n) is in the class Ω(n). And just like you said, I just realized 2^log(n) literally just means n. I always get confused on log rules. Thank you very much for your help!